# IntelliJ 13.1.6 JDK 8 support

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I created a project that `Project SDK` set to `1.8 (1.8.0_25)`. The problem is that even `System` cannot be resolved, if I switched `Project SDK` to `1.7 (1.7.0_71)`, everything works fine. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @ponomandr how to do that?

Comment: `Main menu > File > Invalidate caches`

Comment: @ponomandr tried `Invalidate caches`, didn't work

Comment: Open `File > Project Structure > SDKs` and check if both 1.7 and 1.8 look similar. I mean classpath of 1.8 contains jars. Also try to delete 1.8 SDK here and add from scratch.

Comment: @ponomandr I deleted `1.8` in `Project SDK`, and added it back again, and it worked. thx. But seriously, why it could happen in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64975/discussion-between-ponomandr-and-daiyue).

Answer (score 10):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to `File | Project Structure`.

   - Select `Project` from the left pane. Change `Project language level` to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`.
   - Select `Modules` from the left pane. On the `Sources` tab, select `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.` from the `Language level` drop down.
2. Go to `File | Settings`. From the left pane, find `Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler` (or just search for "Java Compiler"). Next to the name of your module in the `Per-module bytecode version` list, select "1.8" from the `Target bytecode version` drop-down.
3. Restart IntelliJ and re-build your project.

Comment: thank you it was the setting under Modules -> Source that i could not find

Answer (score 1):

lets try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then set project language level to `8.0 lambdas etc`.
and then go: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, go `Compiler | Java Compiler` and on the list `Pre-module bytecode version` on the right set to version 1.8

### Edit:

If it doesn't help, go to `.idea/` folder and open `compiler.xml`, find this chunk of `xml`: (or close to this)

```
<bytecodeTargetLevel target="1.8">
      <module name="something" target="1.6" />
</bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

And set all the version values to 1.8:

```
<bytecodeTargetLevel target="1.8">
      <module name="something" target="1.8" />
</bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Edit the file: *projectname*.iml

Change the line like this:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_5" inherit-compiler-output="false">
```

to be:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8" inherit-compiler-output="false">
```